# SqlServer 2016 - Database Size is too important

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, bigdata, sql-server-2016

Sorry if I make mistakes, I'm French...

I have a database, when I Create it, here's some stats :

1. db size : 16 MB
2. mdf file size : 8 MB
3. ldf file size : 8 MB

DB Mode is SIMPLE, Table compression is PAGE type
I transfer millions of lines and however I use TABLOCK, or, TABLOCKX / HOLDLOCK...
Finaly I have this :

1. db size : 2512 MB
2. mdf file size : 729 MB
3. ldf file size : 1843 MB

WOW ! Just 3 millions lines in my database and Its size grow up to 2.5 GB !

I use Merge, Update, Delete, Insert queries. I execute them with SSIS Job. It's bigdata for pharmaceutical business...

How can reduce db size automatically without shrink manually.
Is there some queries for reduce log size impact or something like this ?

Thx for all !

Comment: Probably [Recovery model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server): FULL. Take a backup or change to simple and shrink.

Comment: Firstly, 3 million records and a 2.5gb database is *not* big data.  Secondly, *why* do you want to reduce the size?  What problems are you having?

Comment: It will only grow again after you shrink it and it will be fragmented across the disk, so why shrink it? Are you concerned about disk space?

Comment: @iamdave Firstly it's just one shot to try but at the end it will insert billions of line. Secondly the problem is : If I have 2.5GB db with only 3 millions records what happen if I have 3 billions records on 1 hundred  of database ? I want to reduce the size... I don't know how...

Comment: @WEI_DBA yes !! After that I will have more than 100 databes which billions lines in each... So if 3 millions lines = 2.5GB what happen after billions of lines ?? I want to reduce it

Comment: If you have `Big Data`, then you should have `Big Disk Drives`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA yes I have ! :)
But I want to optimize it ! If I can... I think there's too much logs and I don't know how to reduce it....  :( I work for a Pharma customer and he is very demanding...

Comment: If the Recovery Model is `Simple`, then you can manually shrink using `DBCC ShrinkFile`. Backup your db first, then shrink. See here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql

Comment: ***I work for a Pharma customer and he is very demanding***  Please do not push for answers.  We are here as a free resource for you, at our own cost.

Comment: Just remember that Shrinking is temporary. It's not a solution. Also, if the Log files are on the same disk as the Data files. Move them to their own disk drive.

Comment: Yeah it's why I want another solution, shrinking is not the solution. And... log files aren't on the same disk. Thank's for all

Answer (score -4):

Set recovery model to simple then shrink transaction log.